# Change datagridview data with a textbox

Tags: c#, sql

I have a datagridview that I want to edit by typing in an employee number in a text box. It will then update the datagridview for that employee number only. Here is my code for my current datagridview that pulls information from all employees in the DB. I need to be able to change the select statement so that it pulls the teller number from the textbox and insert it into the sql statement.

```
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constring))
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
            //Build DataGridView
            try
            {
                sqlAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT TellerNum, SessionName, PrincipleName, SessionDate, Comments, SessionKey FROM [SESSION] ORDER BY TellerNum;", con);
                sqlCommand = new OleDbCommandBuilder(sqlAdapter);

                dataset = new DataSet();
                sqlAdapter.Fill(dataset, "[Session]");
                dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dataset.Tables["[Session]"];

                /*DataTable table1 = GetTable1Data(...);
                DataTable table2 = GetTable2Data(...);

                table1.Merge(table2, true);*/

                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    DataGridViewLinkCell linkCell = new DataGridViewLinkCell();
                    dataGridView1[5, i] = linkCell;
                }

                //Change column names
                foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
                {
                    if (column.HeaderText == "TellerNum")
                        column.HeaderText = "Teller #";
                    if (column.HeaderText == "SessionName")
                        column.HeaderText = "Session";
                    if (column.HeaderText == "PrincipleName")
                        column.HeaderText = "Principle Taught";
                    if (column.HeaderText == "SessionDate")
                        column.HeaderText = "Date of Session";
                    if (column.HeaderText == "Comments")
                        column.HeaderText = "Comments About Session";
                    if (column.HeaderText == "SessionKey")
                        column.HeaderText = " ";
                }
                dataGridView1.Columns[5].Visible = false;

                // Resize the DataGridView columns to fit the newly loaded content.
                dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(
                    DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

In the past I have been able to pull info from a text box like this:

```
                string cmdstring = "UPDATE [EMPLOYEE] SET [Comments] = Comments + @comments  WHERE [TellerNum] = @teller";
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdstring, con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teller", comboBox14.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comments", textBox5.Text);

                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Submitted Successfully");
```

Is there a way to pull information from the textbox to determine which employee information will be displayed?

Comment: Sorry, could you explain the issue a little bit better? I must admit that i don't understand the question.

Comment: I need to edit the data pulled from my DB using a textbox. I want to be able to type in an employee number and pull only information about that employee and display it in a datagridview. My second code snippet is just to show you what I mean by pulling text from a textbox to insert into my sql query.

Comment: So, what you want is to filter the datagridview by the employee number in the textbox?

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to type the employee number into a textbox, hit a button and it will create a datagridview where only that employee information is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is have one combo box above the grid for filtering. Have the filter combobox populate the gridView on cbxFilter_SelectedIndexChanged() ( Query the database according to some sort of relevant field in your database).

Once you have the filtered information you need, you can use a textbox to edit the information in the database @ the selected row. The code you have provided would be relevant to this textbox.

Here is a sample of a search bar. I apologize for the naming conventions of things. You will be able to use it as a reference which is what is important.

```
private void txtSearch_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            sqlHelper.sqlconnection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            sqlHelper.sqlconnection.Open();
            string search = txtSearch.Text;
            string temp;
            temp = sqlHelper.ReplaceValue(cbxWarehouse.Text, true);
            string tableName = "dbo.db_" + temp;
            SqlDataReader myReader = null;

            SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE (StoreNo LIKE'" + search + "') OR " +
            "(Description LIKE '%" + search + "%') OR " +
            "(Name LIKE '%" + search + "%') OR " +
            "(ItemNo LIKE '%" + search + "%') OR " +
            "(StoreName LIKE '%" + search + "') AND Assembly <> 1", sqlHelper.sqlconnection);

            myReader = sql.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            for (int i = 0; i < myReader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(myReader.GetName(i), typeof(string));
            }
            try
            {
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    DataRow row = dt.Rows.Add();
                    for (int i = 0; i < myReader.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        string Val = myReader[i].ToString();
                        row[i] = Val;
                    }
                }
                myReader.Close();
            }
            finally
            {
                gridProducts.DataSource = dt;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            if (myReader != null)
            {
                if (!myReader.IsClosed)
                {
                    myReader.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You can use the code you have for updating via textbox.

Comment: If you need help with the code in this I can give you some sample code. It seems like you are struggling with more of the concept of how it is GOING to work and not so much how it works. A generic search bar that queries your DB may be of interest to you. What you need is a filter, doesn't matter what kind as long as its pulling the data. Once you have that, updating the db at a specific row should be straight forward for you, hence you already have the code for it.

Comment: I would appreciate your sample code for the search bar or filter.

Comment: Thank you for the code. Let me play around with it for a while and I'll let you know what the results are.

Comment: No problem. Sometimes its cool to have a list of all your tables in a combobox. That way you can select a table on the database, and then use a search bar to really narrow down your search.